# Calculate the real sequence length for Variable Sequence Lengths in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I recently came across Danijar Hafner's nice and popular blog about variable sequence lengths [here](https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/). He used the function as follows to calculate the real length for the padded sequence.

```
def length(sequence):
    used = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(sequence), 2))
    length = tf.reduce_sum(used, 1)
    length = tf.cast(length, tf.int32)
    return length
```

However, I felt this length function might be problematic in his [example code](https://gist.github.com/danijar/3f3b547ff68effb03e20c470af22c696) where he applies RNN to the mnist data set. From my understanding, the code treats the rows of a handwritten picture as time steps similar to the following architecture except that he uses the last relevant output for the softmax input. And the example interprets the zero rows in the end as padded. So different digits have different length and thus can be used to represent the variable length sequence. [image: this architecture]

However, above length function also treats the zero rows in the beginning of the sequence as padded. For example, in the following picture, the real length should be 26, yet the function gets 20.

Is here anything wrong about it???

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it should be 26? From my reading, it calculates the number of rows containing non-black pixels.

Comment: @geometrikal  It do calculate the number of rows containing non-black pixels. But in the case of sequences of variable length, the function is supposed to calculate the length of the un-padded sequences. Is it not that padded rows should be in the end of time steps?

Comment: Yes I think I see what you mean. It should be the be the index of the last row with white pixels, as he does not appear to cut off the starting rows.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the author is trying to be "cute" using tensorflow to recompute a sequence length in tensorflow instead of simply providing it. I think there is no valid reason of doig so.

- the information is already known, it could be simply provided
- the recomputation relies on an extra assumption that entries are never zero

This last assumption is definitely problematic, one could imagine many situations where zeros are perfectly legitimate inputs. One could try to fix this convention using `inf` or `nan` values instead, but why bother?

Btw, the post is rather old, and the clever trick used for slicing is now irrelevant, as tensorflow does now support numpy-style slicing.